# Getting all records that are 3months old in Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

I need to find all records that are exactly 3months old in Postgres

My query looks as follows.

SELECT * FROM adds WHERE adtype = 'CL' AND DATEDIFF(dstart,DATE(now())) = DATE_SUB(curdate(),interval 3 month);

But this does not seem to work. Any advise help with this query will be helpful. I can calculate this in PHP but want to find out the value using a Postgres query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are comparing a time period to a point in time.
2. Is there really a DATEDIFF in Postgres?
3. Are you sure you need the records of that one day exactly 3 months in the past? Unusual application.

I'd suggest: `WHERE DATE(dstart) = DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL '3 month'`

Comment: = I did not know whether DATEDIFF exist in POSTGRES or not. 3. Yes I do, why = does not concern you, and yes I'm sure

Comment: @Roland- Wow, what a prick. You were the one asking for help guy.

Comment: @Roland - So you just agreed w/ me that you were being a prick.